# apache2 is not working after installing it

Tags: server, apache2

I installed `apache2` several times using

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Here is the image of my terminal:

[image: image of terminal]

Then I tried to open `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` on my browser, but it is not working.

I checked again if `apache2` is already installed using:

```
apache2 -v
```

and the result is:

```
The program 'apache2' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install apache2-bin
Do you want to install it? (N/y)
```

When I entered `Y` it showed this:

[image: "apache2 -v" output]

I also entered this command:

```
sudo apache2ctl start
```

and it shows this:

```
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 143: /usr/sbin/apache2ctl: /usr/sbin/apache2: not found
Action 'start' failed.
```

It looks like I have missing packages.

These are the installed `apache2` packages I have:

```
apache2                     install
apache2-bin                 install
apache2-data                install
apache2-doc                 install
apache2-utils               install
libapache2-mod-php5.6       install
libapache2-mod-svn          install
libapache2-svn              install
```

I have also used `whereis apache` before to locate the Apache directories and instead of using `purge` or `remove`, I deleted all the directories shown on my terminal manually by using `rm -rf`.

Does this affect the future installation of `apache2`?

Comment: Did you tried `sudo service apache2 restart` ?

Comment: yes. even sudo service apache2 stop then sudo service apache2 start, are not working

Comment: maybe you are not doing it right and missing some upgrades. Follow steps that is described in this blog: [https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/apache/apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04]

Comment: @sgiri the site is currently down.

i already did this process before in installing apache, but this time it is not working.

Comment: Reinstall `apache2-bin` using `apt-get install --reinstall apache2-bin`

Comment: localhost is still not working. 

the terminal also says, After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.

does this mean that installing apache2-bin is not successful?

Comment: Voted as "Can't be reproduced", since the issue was solved after a restart.

Answer (score 1):

`apache2` is now working. I just needed to restart my PC after installing the `apache2` package.

Answer (score -1):

Try to install LAMP maybe, because of library dependencies it could not install properly. 
[Install LAMP in Ubuntu 16](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04)